# bind ngChange event to dynamically generated controls

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I need to generate the html dynamically based on the content returned from server using `$http.get`.
The issue i am facing is the onchange event defined using ngChange does not fire for the `select`.

Below is the angular code -

```
var appModule = angular.module('frameworkModule',['ngRoute', 'ngGrid']); 

appModule.controller('homeController', 
            ['$scope', 'valuesService', '$http', '$templateCache', 
            function ($scope, valuesService, $http, $templateCache) {

       getData();
       function getData() {
            $http.get('/api/values').success(function (item) {
                var element = $("#filters-div");
                var select = item.Name + "<select id='" + item.id + "' ng-change='valueChanged(this)'>";
                    for (var j = 0; j < item.Values.length; j++) {
                        var optionValue = item.Values[j].ID;
                        var optionText = item.Values[j].Name;
                        select += "<option value='" + optionValue + "'>" + optionText + "</option>";
                    }
                    select += "</select>";
            $templateCache.put('filters-template', select );
            element.append(select);
            });
        }

      $scope.valueChanged= function (element) {
         //how can i get this event fired?
         alert("change event fired");
       }
}]);
```

Here is how my html is -

```
<div id="filters-div" ng-include="filters-template"></div>
```

Can you please let me know what am i doing wrong in my code? I apologize i am new to angular, there may be something silly that i am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to create some HTML not inside template you must to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). But in this situation you can generate HTML inside template. Also you don't really need to use jQuery and you must not ever manipulate DOM inside AngularJS controller. Here is my example of how you can render select box:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="MainController">
        <select id="{{item.id}}" data-ng-model="option">
            <option
                data-ng-repeat="value in item.Values"
                data-ng-value='value.ID'>{{value.Name}}</option>
        </select>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', []);
            app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $timeout) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.item = {
                        'id': 'item_id',
                        'Values': [
                            {
                                'ID': '1',
                                'Name': 'First'
                            },
                            {
                                'ID': '2',
                                'Name': 'Second'
                            },
                            {
                                'ID': '3',
                                'Name': 'Third'
                            }
                        ]
                    };
                    $scope.option = $scope.item['Values'][0]['Name'];
                }, 1000);
                
                $scope.$watch('option', function (newVal) {
                    if (newVal) {
                        console.log("Selected option " + newVal);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have used $timeout to simulate AJAX request. You can also add ng-show to template so you will not display select box if it is not filled with data.